# How to rotate a text element with pyleap?

Tags: python

How I can rotate a text element using the PYLEAP package?

I've tried the following, but it doesn't recognize the `rotation` keyword

```
objtorotate = Text("MADE IN INDIA", 200, 200, 11, "black", "calibri").draw()
objtorotate.rotation = 90
```

Answer (score 0):

`rotation` is not an attribute of the draw() function.
Apply separately to the object

```
from pyleap import repeat, run, Text

objtorotate = Text("MADE IN INDIA", 200, 200, 11, "red", "calibri")

def show(dt):
    objtorotate.rotation = 90
    objtorotate.draw()


repeat(show)
run()
```

Changed text to red given the black background.
[image: Screenshot]